# How to exclude some column from history table in temporal table

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables, sql-server-2022

I have a same question in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76943485/1539100) about this, But I hope to find answer here

I have temporal table like below

```sql
-- Create a Temporal Table
CREATE TABLE dbo.Sample
(
  SampleId int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , SampleDate date NOT NULL
  , Data1 varchar(50)
  , Data2 varchar(50)
  -- Other fields...
  , SysStartTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START
  , SysEndTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END
  , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)
 )
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.SampleHistory));
```

I want to say all of changes in Data2 does not store in `HISTORY_TABLE`. In another word, in very large and big tables I just need few columns for auditing so I want to exclude other columns to reduce DB size and improve performance (in some cases most frequent changes in table occur on non-auditable column)

**How to do it? (in another word how to exclude to tracking changes of Data2)**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I explicitly say what I need

Comment: Asking the same question in a different site doesn't change the answer that what you are asking isn't possible as temporal tables always record the whole row and are triggered by any write to the row

Comment: Perhaps a better solution for you would be change data capture, which allows you to [specify which columns you'd like to track changes in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-enable-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#----ncaptured_column_list).

Comment: Temporal tables are _not_ the tool for auditing, so don't use them like that.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom auditing solution that uses change data capture, as suggested in the comments.

History tables record the entire row for a temporal table, as documented. You cannot customize what is recorded. The same goes for the ledger feature.